# Dirty checkbox still checked when ng-model set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple problem but I don't know how to solve it in AngularJS 1.4. Basically, I have a form with 1 checkbox and 1 button. The button should uncheck the checkbox and set a boolean variable (ng-model of checkbox) to false.

However, I cannot do like this *when the checkbox is checked by users (checkbox state is dirty)* and the **button cannot do anything to uncheck this checkbox**.

Any idea to solve this problem?

```
<button ng-click="uncheckCheckbox()">uncheck</button> 
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="displayWMSLayer" ng-change="showWMSLayerOnGlobe(displayWMSLayer)"/>
```

A rough Javascript code to show what functions do:

```
function uncheckCheckbox() {
    $scope.displayWMSLayer = false;
    alert("Checkbox is unchecked automatically");
}

function showWMSLayerOnGlobe(status) {
    if (status) {
       alert("Checkbox is checked manually");
    } else {
       alert("Checkbox is unchecked manually");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it looks like this? http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/47596/

Comment: @rtbm yes, your example is what I wanted to have, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this way

**JS**

```
$scope.checkboxModel = {
  displayWMSLayer: false  
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checkboxModel.displayWMSLayer" ng-change="showWMSLayerOnGlobe(checkboxModel.displayWMSLayer)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly, you just want to have a button to uncheck the checkbox.

In case i am correct then why don't you just try this way ?

**HTML:-**

```
 <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <button ng-click="uncheck()">uncheck</button> 
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="displayWMSLayer"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:-**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.displayWMSLayer = false;
    $scope.uncheck=function(){
        $scope.displayWMSLayer=$scope.displayWMSLayer?$scope.displayWMSLayer=false:$scope.displayWMSLayer;
        }
}
```